# need code to display mysql database on webpage with pagination in it using angular.js and node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs

i need code of angular.js and node.js to display mysql database table on webpage and the table should have pagination on it .please help
 SELECT * FROM Users

Comment: What you had tried? I suggest to you datatable for your requirement

Comment: sorry i was not clear enough i meant to say i need to display my datatable

Comment: bro, without any code snippet no one can help you here. You have to try and if you stuck in error then ask here